# MultiBinding Shows Build Error. Is this a fault in xaml or the converter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, converters, multibinding

From within a custom Control.

Having tried , without much success to get PriorityBinding to work I've decided to look at MultiBinding instead.

In xaml the binding is set like this;

```
 <StackPanel>
   <Image Style="{StaticResource vtlImageStyle}">
       <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultivalueConverter}">
          <Binding Path="FirstImage"
                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
          <Binding Path="DefaultFirstButtonImage"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
        </MultiBinding>
       </Image.Source>
   </Image>
 </StackPanel>
```

and the converter being used is defined like this:

```
Public Class VtlDefaultToChosenImageConverter
Implements IMultiValueConverter

'Expects images to be passed in as user chosen followed by default so that user chosen will always triumph over default.'

Public Function Convert(values() As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IMultiValueConverter.Convert
    Dim img As ImageSource = Nothing
    Dim img1 As ImageSource = CType(values(0), ImageSource)
    Dim img2 As ImageSource = CType(values(1), ImageSource)
    If Not IsNothing(img1) Then
        img = img1
    Else
        If Not IsNothing(img2) Then
            img = img2
        End If
    End If

    Return img
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes() As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object() Implements IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Function
End Class
```

The idea is that in the event of there being no FirstImage set by the consumer of the control it should fall back on the default image. In this basic guise this works.

Now if I (when consuming the control) add my own choice of FirstImage the ide shows a build error in the ide, and the new FirstImage property is underlined in xaml.  When one actually runs the application the control will compile and show the new FirstImage.  Should I expect to see this sort of error, or is there a mistake in the way that I have either definded the binding in xaml or the actual converter?

[image]

Comment: What is the actuall code for VtlDataNavigator, because there maybe some code that needs to be ignored during design time by putting it inside if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) then you do some stuff

Comment: Do you really need a converter? Why can't you just change the `FirstImage` property type to an `ImageSource`?

Comment: @MikeEason  FirstImage Property is a dependencyProperty of Type Image Source, as is DefaultFirstButtonImage.

Comment: @adminSoftDK  Are you referring to the Generic.Xaml (it's a customControl) or the .vb file.

Comment: I was asking for the code that makes VtlDataNavigator control. If its a custom control then I guess it has some code inside it.